# Is there a way to keep the search results after leaving and coming back to a page?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a page on which you can call a popup where you insert keywords. With those, my API is called. When I click on an item I searched for, another site opens (a detailed view on the item). When I go back, the search page is being loaded completely new - and the search results are gone.

I want the search results to remain but have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in a so called client-side storage like LocalStorage before API call or when results are received and read it on page load for example. Read more about usage with vue.js [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html)

Some example code to read a stored value from local storage: (this could be your search criteria)

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: '',
    age: 0
  },
  mounted() {
    if (localStorage.name) {
      this.name = localStorage.name;
    }
    if (localStorage.age) {
      this.age = localStorage.age;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    persist() {
      localStorage.name = this.name;
      localStorage.age = this.age;
      console.log('now pretend I did more stuff...');
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I try to get it working.
It seems like I was able to store it but I can't restore it so far.

Comment: Its should work. If you read the docs this is also the recommended way. Good luck!

Comment: You can also try pure js for reading it just to get it to work. Like LocalStorage.Getitem('xyz')

Comment: I had to save an array of objects. I did the docs of vue showed an example that worked very well! I just need to find a way to clear it properly.
[link](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html#Working-with-Complex-Values)

Comment: Great. Glad to help. I usually just throw in some json and read it back