# Determine If the user comes from a specific URL or hits 'back' in the browser in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have created a vue app which does not load all the results on first fetch as there are too many and Id like the page speed to be optimal.

So the user lands on the page which contains a search box, then perform a search and go to the relevant result page (this is a URL and not part of the vue app)  then they might come back to the results page. Id like the results to load if the user comes back to the page or comes from a set the set of results URL's.

Is this possible? I have used sessionstorage to retain the search parameters in the search box but I cant work out how to get the referrer. It just display as my local host address.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: An idea! you can move the browser to a specific page before redirecting to the target. Adding a middle page for redirecting or manipulating the url's parameters can give you a hint for later use. HomePage -> MiddlePage (replace url or add a flag in query) -> TargetPage

Comment: Thanks you! I ended up using local storage and following the example on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58582348/is-there-a-way-to-keep-the-search-results-after-leaving-and-coming-back-to-a-pag